# Change of variable and partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let us suppose we consider the following change of variables $(t,r)\rightarrow (T,R)$ with
$$
f(t,r) \frac{\partial}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \quad(1)\\
g(t,r) \frac{\partial}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial}{\partial R}\quad(2)
$$
I suppose that it means we have $T\equiv T(t,r)$ and $R\equiv R(t,r)$. What I don't understand is, let us suppose we apply the first relation (1) to $r$ which gives
$$
f(t,r) \frac{\partial r}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial r}{\partial T}
$$
But because $\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}=0$ we should have $\frac{\partial r}{\partial T}=0$ and hence $r$ as a function of $R$ only or equivalently $R$ a function of $r$ only. But clearly from relation (2) we should have R(**t**,r)

Comment: Sorry, why does $\partial_t r = 0$? Why can't $r = r(t)$?

Comment: Because this is my assumption from the beginning. Let us suppose it's a physical problem with time (t) and space (r)

Comment: Said differently, if $r=r(t)$ then there is obviously no problem because I would have only 1 real coordinate $t$